# index on lots of range columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a large table with 20 columns containing int4ranges. Most of the ranges are infinite, but some have specific values like (10,100). Typically, I only get 3-4 columns with an integer value as input. I am trying to determine the most effective structure to utilize an index as optimally as possible.

Here is an example:

**DB:**

| id | money_1 | money_2 | .. money_80 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1-100 | infinity - infinity | infinity - infinity |
| B | 0 - 10 | 100-1000 | infinity - infinity |

Example queries I encounter:

- `money_1 @> 5 AND money_2 @> 110` (matches A,B)
- `money_1 @> 1000` (matches nothing)
- `money_2 @> 110` (matches B)

I am wondering if there is a smart way to construct an index for this type of situation.

PS: Please keep in mind that I have 20 of these range columns and most of the time half of them have a range that is not infinite

Comment: The only way to use indexes here is to have a GiST index on each of the columns. You could do better if you didn't allow arbitrary `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: right now iam constructing the where statement dynamically, but nothing is stopping me from not doing that. If the structure of a where statement is always the same, how would i improve here?

Comment: You can define a multi-column GIST index.